# android HttpPost send data in xml format to server

Tags: android, http-post

I need to send the login and username data to the server which is mentioned below

```
     <req_data><username></username><password></password></req_data>
```

Please suggest me how to send this username and password to server and get response from server

Answer (score 0):

Try using `HTTPUrlConnection`, you can find an example method below. It accepts your server's URL and String content (your XML string). 
Post request will be made to the URL and the content provided will be stored in the POST header, which you can retrieve on your server side application (if using PHP try `$headerContent = file_get_contents('php://input');`)

```
public static String excutePost(String targetURL, String content){
URL url;
HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
try {
  //Create connection
  url = new URL(targetURL);
  connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
  connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
       "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 
           Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  

  connection.setUseCaches (false);
  connection.setDoInput(true);
  connection.setDoOutput(true);

  //Send request
  DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
              connection.getOutputStream ());
  wr.writeBytes (content);
  wr.flush ();
  wr.close ();

  //Get Response    
  InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
  String line;
  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
  while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(line);
    response.append('\r');
  }
  rd.close();
  return response.toString();

} catch (Exception e) {

  e.printStackTrace();
  return null;

} finally {

  if(connection != null) {
    connection.disconnect(); 
  }
} 
}
```

You will find your server's response as the returned String value of this method. You can parse it to Java objects using your favourite parser.